# on mouseover function not executing for d3 line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to implement something similar to this, when mousing over a particular circle representing a data point, show a tooltip with its data: 
http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369

However, I have multiple lines instead of just one line.

- EDIT, have attached a plunker code with the code, my apologies for not having included it earlier: http://plnkr.co/edit/cYSASsNWcFFkLp9pKh0q?p=preview

Currently, I have made the circles using this using each line's individual dataset, but it seems like when I mouseover the particular circle, there is no mouseover event. Tried console logging but nothing appears too.

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("fill", colors[0])
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return x(d.year) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d["less than 7"]) })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      // console.log("index", i);
      // console.log(d[i]["less than 7"]);
      // div.html(d[i]["less than 7"])
      // .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      // .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px")
      // .style("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      div.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
    })
```

Comment: Does not seem to have any mistakes from this code. Have you try console.log("String") to see if the function is called? The i variable in your console.log call is not in the function(d,i)

Comment: can you a minimum verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi @Cyril, my apologies for not having included a sample code earlier, have attached a plunker url with the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/cYSASsNWcFFkLp9pKh0q?p=preview.

Comment: @LoredraL  my mistake on having omitted the i variable, was trying to console log just d earlier on but nothing appeared either ways, have attached a plunker code now - [Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/cYSASsNWcFFkLp9pKh0q?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error console is giving you several useful errors with your code.

`div` is undefined. You are using it like a variable, but you never define it anywhere. I think you want `tooltip.html` not `div.html`. You may want to select the div within `tooltip`-- not sure.

Also you are trying to access your data with `d[i]["less than 7"]`. You should write `d` to the console, because it doesn't appear to be an array at this point. I think you want `d["less than 7"]`.

Doing this gets the tooltips to work for me:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
  console.log("index", i, d);
  console.log(d["8 to 14 years"]);
  dotTooltip.html(d["8 to 14 years"])
  .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) + "px")
  .style("opacity", 1)
})
```

The graph in your Plunker, however, is only showing a line along the x-axis for me.

Comment: He only draw 2 age groups, and all of them are 0 except year 2014. But you are right about the rest

Comment: Thank you! Yep, only drew 2 age groups/lines. Also realised that the console.log was probably not working because I had another mousemove event, which was not in the plunker. Hence without it, the console.log / individual tooltip worked. Would try exploring ways to implement both, but if not possible, would stick to individual tooltip.